# Get HTTP request parameters in Spring HTTPMessageConverter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, converters, http-request-parameters

I am using Spring's AbstractHttpMessageConverter to allow me instantiate my own object.

**Converter**

```
    public class PaypalIPNHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<IPNMessage> {

    public PaypalIPNHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz == IPNMessage.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected IPNMessage readInternal(Class<? extends IPNMessage> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        //Converts HTTPRequest into map<string,string> that IPNMessage can then parse
        String requestString = IOUtils.toString(inputMessage.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        Map<String, String[]> requestMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (String keyValue : requestString.split("&")) { //each key value is delimited by &
            String[] pairs = keyValue.split("=", 2); // = pairs a key to a value
            requestMap.put(pairs[0], pairs[1].split(",")); // , splits multiple values for that key
        }
        return new IPNMessage(requestMap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(IPNMessage ipnMessage, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    }
}
```

In readINternal(), I am passed a HttpInputMessage object, which only has getBody() function that produces an InputStream of the HTTPRequest.

I have tried to write my own code to parse and build a ParameterMap but it does not always work if the urlencoding is different.

Is there anyway I can get Spring's **WebRequest** or **HttpServletRequest** object from the converter and use there wonderful getParameterMap() function?

**TL;DR**

Is there anyway to use WebRequest or HTTPServletRequest in the MessageConverter instead of HttpInput so I can use the wonderful getParameterMap() function, instead of reinventing the wheel?

Thanks

Comment: You can usually just autowire HttpServletRequest to spring managed beans (e.g. just add this as a field: `@Autowired HttpServletRequest request;` ). Be aware that Spring framework did not intend you to access url parameters in message converters. There might be better places to plug in your functionality (conversion service? argument resolvers?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how it is implemented in Spring FormHttpMessageConverter. It tokenizes request parameter using & just like your solution. However it dtermines the charset to use from the Content-Type request header if provided. Otherwise it uses default UTF-8

```
//extract from FormHttpMessageConverter
public MultiValueMap<String, String> read(Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String, ?>> clazz,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        MediaType contentType = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
        Charset charset = (contentType.getCharSet() != null ? contentType.getCharSet() : this.charset);
        String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputMessage.getBody(), charset);

        String[] pairs = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(body, "&");
        MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(pairs.length);
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf('=');
            if (idx == -1) {
                result.add(URLDecoder.decode(pair, charset.name()), null);
            }
            else {
                String name = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), charset.name());
                String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), charset.name());
                result.add(name, value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the current request using the following code

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```